# Isekai manga where the main character is reincarnated as a king

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this manga a few years ago. It was about a teenager who used to live in Japan and had good information passed down from his grandfather that he uses to be king of the country he is reincarnated to.

He proceeds to pass down knowledge from the modern world to the fantasy world he currently lives in, and he modernizes his whole country.

Comment: I know you think you've said everything you remember, but can you visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if that promtps more details that you can edit in?

Comment: Like were there common fantasy races? Did the people in this other world look Japanese? Did the teenager? When reincarnated, did he wake up in an older body? Start as a baby or a small child? Is there magic? Gods?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is [How a Realist Hero Rebuilt the Kingdom](https://mangadex.org/title/21809/genjitsushugi-yuusha-no-oukoku-saikenki), though there is not a lot to work with in the question.

Starts out with the Main character getting advice from his grandfather.  Then he is summoned to another world. The mantle of kingship is handed over to him after going over all the financial information about the kingdom and it is explained to the king how to obtain enough money to pay off a larger empire.  It then goes on to him introducing modern ideas and moves towards modernizing the whole country.